# NServiceBus 5 with RabbitMQ defining an EndpointName with single broker queue

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, nservicebus

I am using NServiceBus hosted in my own process with the RabbitMQ transport and have just upgraded from NServiceBus 4.6.5 to NServiceBus 5.0.0.

Previously I had my endpoint configured like this:

```
var queueName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["queuename"];

        Configure.ScaleOut(s => s.UseSingleBrokerQueue());
        Configure.Transactions.Disable();
        Configure.Features.Enable<Sagas>();
        Configure.Features.Disable<SecondLevelRetries>();
        Configure.Serialization.Xml();

        return
            Configure.With(typeof(SomeClass).Assembly, typeof(RabbitMQ).Assembly)
                     .DefineEndpointName(queueName)
                     .DefaultBuilder()
                     .RavenPersistenceWithStore(DocumentStore.Value)
                     .DefiningCommandsAs(type => type.Namespace != null && type.Namespace.EndsWith("Contracts.Commands"))
                     .DefiningEventsAs(type => type.Namespace != null && type.Namespace.EndsWith("Contracts.Events"))
                     .DefiningMessagesAs(type => type.Namespace != null && type.Namespace.EndsWith("Contracts.Messages"))
                     .RijndaelEncryptionService()
                     .UseTransport<RabbitMQ>()
                     .PurgeOnStartup(false)
                     .UnicastBus()
                     .RunHandlersUnderIncomingPrincipal(false)
                     .ImpersonateSender(false)
                     .LoadMessageHandlers()
                     .DisableTimeoutManager()
                     .RavenSagaPersister()
                     .RavenSubscriptionStorage()
                     .UseRavenTimeoutPersister()
                     .CreateBus()
                     .Start
                (() => {
                     DependencyManager.ConfigureServiceBusDependencies();
                     Configure.Instance.LicensePath(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "NServiceBus-Licence.xml"));
                     Configure.Instance.ForInstallationOn<Windows>().Install();
                 });
```

Which worked great and created a queue called "some.appropriate.queue.name", which was taken from my app.config file.

However, when upgrading to NServiceBus 5.0.0.0 I used the new configuration api and configured my endpoint like this:

```
var queueName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["queuename"];

        var configuration = new BusConfiguration();
        configuration.EndpointName(queueName);
        configuration.LicensePath(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "NServiceBus-Licence.xml"));

        configuration.ScaleOut().UseSingleBrokerQueue();
        configuration.Transactions().Disable();
        configuration.EnableFeature<Sagas>();
        configuration.DisableFeature<SecondLevelRetries>();
        configuration.UseSerialization<XmlSerializer>();

        configuration.UsePersistence<RavenDBPersistence>()
                     .SetDefaultDocumentStore(DocumentStore.Value)
                     .For(Storage.Sagas, Storage.Subscriptions, Storage.Timeouts);

        configuration.Conventions()
                     .DefiningCommandsAs(type => type.Namespace != null && type.Namespace.EndsWith("Contracts.Commands"));
        configuration.Conventions().DefiningEventsAs(type => type.Namespace != null && type.Namespace.EndsWith("Contracts.Events"));
        configuration.Conventions()
                     .DefiningMessagesAs(type => type.Namespace != null && type.Namespace.EndsWith("Contracts.Messages"));

        configuration.RijndaelEncryptionService();
        configuration.PurgeOnStartup(false);
        configuration.UseTransport<RabbitMQTransport>();


        configuration.RegisterComponents(DependencyManager.ConfigureServiceBusDependencies);
        configuration.AssembliesToScan
            (typeof(SomeClass).Assembly, typeof(RabbitMQTransport).Assembly);

        configuration.EnableInstallers();

        var bus = Bus.Create(configuration);
```

And now it creates a queue called "some.appropriate.queue.name.MyLaptopName". So NServiceBus is tacking the machine name onto the end of my queue name even though I have configure the scaleout option to use a single broker queue.

Is this a bug, or was the way it worked in 4.6.5 the bug and the machine name should always be tacked onto the end of the queue name even when using a single broker queue?

Any help with this issue is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to support both callbacks and pubsub seamlessly when scaling out we had to change v2.0.0 to have a separate callback receiver. You can turn that off by calling

```
configuration.UseTransport<RabbitMQTransport>()
.DisableCallbackReceiver();
```

Here is the full doco page that explains all this in detail:

http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/rabbitmq/configuration-api

.SingleBrokerQueue() is ignored and you can safely remove it. (will be obsoleted in v6 of the NServiceBus core)

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the issues reported for NServiceBus on github I cam accross this https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/issues/2412
which states that ScaleOut().x is obsolete and will be removed from 6.0.0.

So I took that out of my configuration to see if that resolves my issue. It didn't :( but it got me thinking about what it meant. So really the machine name should always be specified, even localhost.

So I changed this line:

```
configuration.EndpointName(queueName);
```

to this:

```
configuration.EndpointName(string.Format("{0}@localhost", queueName));
```

and the endpoint then created the queue without suffixing the machine name.

Comment: Stackoverflow says I have to wait 2 days before I can.

Comment: OK well wait 2 days and then please mark as your solution! ;P